# How To Embed MonoTouch.Dialog Elements into ViewController?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, radioelement

I am trying to use this:

[Adding a Monotouch.Dialog to a standard view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868553/adding-a-monotouch-dialog-to-a-standard-view)

I can see the view elements when I do this... however clicking on one of the radio elements does not do anything (showing the checkbox for example). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code that I am using inside ViewDidLoad()

```
    var rootElement = new RootElement("Question Text", new RadioGroup("answer", 0))
    {
       new Section()
       {
            new RadioElement("Answer A", "answer"),
            new RadioElement("Answer B", "answer"),
            new RadioElement("Answer C", "answer"),
            new RadioElement("Answer D", "answer")
        }
     };

     _questionDialogViewController = new DialogViewController(rootElement);
     _questionDialogViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString(AppDelegate.EventModel.MainBackgroundColor);
     _questionDialogViewController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 250, 864, 500);
     View.AddSubview(_questionDialogViewController.View);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was an issue with the dialog controller expanding past the edge of the viewcontroller.

The solution was to add a middle UIView as a container to force the DialogController to stay within the correct bounds.

The correct code ended up being:

```
var rootElement = new RootElement("Question Text", new RadioGroup("answer", 0))
{
   new Section()
   {
        new RadioElement("Answer A", "answer"),
        new RadioElement("Answer B", "answer"),
        new RadioElement("Answer C", "answer"),
        new RadioElement("Answer D", "answer")
    }
 };

 _questionDialogViewController = new DialogViewController(rootElement);
 _questionDialogViewController.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString(AppDelegate.EventModel.MainBackgroundColor);
 _questionDialogViewController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 964, 500);

 var answerContainer = new UIView(new RectangleF(30, 150, 964, 500));
 answerContainer.AddSubview(_questionDialogViewController.View);

 View.AddSubview(answerContainer);
```